# On cophenetic correlation for dendrogram clustering

Tags: clustering, classification

Consider the context of a dendrogram clustering. Let us call *original dissimilarities* the distances between the individuals. After constructing the dendrogram we define the *cophenetic dissimilarity* between two individuals as the distance between the clusters to which these individuals belong.

Some people consider that the correlation between the original dissimilarities and the cophenetic dissimilarities (called *cophenetic correlation*) is a "suitability index" of the classification. This sounds totally puzzling to me. My objection does not rely on the particular choice of the Pearson correlation, but on the general idea that any link between the original dissimilarities and the cophenetic dissimilarities could be related to the suitability of the classification.

Do you agree with me, or could you present some argument supporting the use of the cophenetic correlation as a suitability index for the dendrogram classification ?

Comment: You don't explain your objection to the (quite intuitive)`general idea that any link between the original dissimilarities and the cophenetic dissimilarities could be related to the suitability of the classification`. Classification should reflect original dissimilarities. Dendrogramic classification's basic feature to do this is via cophenetic dissimilarity. Is there smth. wrong?

Comment: By the way, one should not mix concept of _hierarchical (agglometative) clustering_ with _hierarchical (dendrogramic) classification_. The clustering produces its dendrogram as a _process_ report; it doesn't claim it to be _hierarchical classification result_.

Comment: @ttnphns My objection is simple: I don't see any argument that the cophenetic correlation is a suitability index, so I do not have any reason to believe it is a suitability index (similarly I do not believe in ghosts because I do not have any reason to believe in ghosts). Why do you say that classification should reflect original dissimilarity ? This sounds dogmatic to me. What is bad if my classification does not reflect original dissimilarities ?

Comment: @ttnphns In regards to your second comment : sorry I don't know the difference between clustering and classification. This is an interesting point but, I think, not important for the present question (?)

Comment: Cophenetic correlation was proposed for "dogmatic" classifications only - where the classification _should_ reflect pairwise dissimilarities, thence the notion of usefulness of (cophenetic) correlation follows immideately.

Comment: You might want to read this [paper](http://www.faculty.biol.ttu.edu/Strauss/Phylogenetics/Readings/Farris1969.pdf) on cophenetic correlation

Comment: @ttnphns Ok this is a dogmaticity index ? :) I took a quick look to this paper. It does not seem to advocate the cophenetic correlation, isn't it ? Moreover the cophenetic correlation is always higher for the average linkage than the complete linkage. It seems puzzling to conclude that the average linkage is "better" than the complete linkage.

Comment: Please don't be wicked. Nobody "advocates" it. It is known to be somewhat useful for some classification tasks. So let us end the discission here. BTW, one should'd generally compare clustering techniques such as average and complete linkage - they optimise different things and are apt for different situations.

Comment: @ttnphns Sorry, I really did not want to seem wicked. My english is rather poor, I speak as I can (in limited time since I'm at work). Please apologize. Farris seems to claim that the cophenetic correlation is appropriate in some situations, not in other situations (as we might expect with everything in statistics)

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent  I have nothing to contribute as an answer to your question but I have been reading the dialog.  Nothing you said sounded offensive to me.  Also you said you didn't know the difference between classification and clustering and I haven't seen that simple question answered. It is the differece between what the machine learning people call supervised and unsupervised learning. In classification you know all the class labels for your data and use that information to construct a classification rule for future cases that don't have labels.  In cluster you have no labelling.

Comment: You form groups by observing how the data clusters assuming points close in the feature space should be put into the same group and other further away in another or other group(s).

Comment: @MichaelChernick Thanks. Maybe ttnphns has not appreciated my joke about the dogmaticity index ;)

Comment: @Stephane, I _did_ appreciate your joke, and found it silly and irrelevant (excuse me). It was wicked, not offensive to me.

Answer (score 2):

> ... is a "suitability index" of the classification

To me it's not right clear what is meant by that. The way I got it, is that

> the correlation between the original dissimilarities and the cophenetic dissimilarities (called cophenetic correlation)

**is a measure of the hierarchical structure among the observations**, i. e. their distances. That is to say the dissimilarities to observations in a different cluster are preferably similar.
Considering to datasets A and B clustered using euclidean distance and complete linkage...
[image]
...even without having a look at the cophenetic distance map or computing cophenetic correlation, one can see, that the cophenetic correlation of A is higher than that of B.
In a hierarchy there are levels. So the CC tells about whether distances to observations on the same level (cluster) are similar.

For the sake of completeness: The cophenetic correlations are CC(A) = 0.936 and CC(B) = 0.691

Comment: I wish I were more expert on this. I don't quite follow your example w/ the heatmaps. What is it that you see that makes it obvious the CC(A) > the CC(B)? Eg, if the upper triangles were cophenetic distances & the lower triangles were original distances, & both displayed similar patterns, then I would recognize that the CC would be high, etc. W/ these I'm not sure how to make such an inference. Is it just that A will naturally give rise to better clustering & so the resulting CC will just have to end up matching well?