# Validate dendrogram in cluster analysis: What is the meaning of cophenetic correlation coefficient?

Tags: r, correlation, statistical-significance, clustering, hierarchical-clustering

I want to calculate the cophenetic correlation coefficient.
Reading previous posts

[Comparison of cophenetic correlation coefficients on different data sets](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92546/comparison-of-cophenetic-correlation-coefficients-on-different-data-sets)

[On cophenetic correlation for dendrogram clustering](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33066/on-cophenetic-correlation-for-dendrogram-clustering)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639794/in-r-how-can-i-plot-a-similarity-matrix-like-a-block-graph-after-clustering-d

I used the `cophenetic` function in the package `stats`. 
As far as I understand the results are cophenetic distances for the hierarchical clustering, in a new object of class `dis`.

```
coph<-cophenetic(hclsut_result)
```

To have an overview I clustered the cophenetic matrix, and I obtained the same clustering  as the one performed on my dataset.

However, I wanted to have a unique value that indicates the fidelity with which my clustering represents my distance matrix. Therefore, I correlated the `dis_matrix_for_my_dataset` with the `coph`.

```
cor(euclidian_dist, coph)
```

Am I understanding right that the value I obtain indicates the **cophenetic correlation coefficient**?

Answer (score 5):

The cophenetic correlation coefficient is defined as the linear correlation between the dissimilarities $d_{ij}$ between each pair of observations $(i,j)$ and their corresponding cophenetic distances $d_{ij}^{coph}$, which is the intergroup dissimilarity at which the observations $i, j$ first merged together in the same cluster.

So you get the cophenetic correlation coefficient $CCC$ by calculating the correlation between those values. Let $D$ be the distance matrix according to $d$ and $Z$ be the distance matrix according to $d^{coph}$, $\bar{D}, \bar{Z}$ denotes the means of $d_{ij}$ and $d_{ij}^{coph}$ respectively, then

$CCC(D,Z) = Cor(D,Z) = \frac{\sum\limits_{i<j} (D_{ij} - \bar{D})(Z_{ij} - \bar{Z}) }{\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i<j} (D_{ij} - \bar{D})^2 \sum\limits_{i<j} (Z_{ij} - \bar{Z})^2 }}$

(see: [Mathworks Documentation: cophenetic correlation coefficient](https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/cophenet.html))

This should be equal to what you have done by calculating

```
cor(euclidian_dist, coph)
```

So, I think your assumption is correct.